# Generate csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to generate a csv file from a php array containing  data. I am able to generate the csv file without any issue. But am little struggling with heading of file.

Here is my codes.

```
public function download_csv_file (){
    $total_call_log=get_overage_report();
    $start_date=date("Y-m-01");
    $end_date=date("Y-m-d");
    $filename="OveragesReport-$end_date";
    $heading="Bill Period From :$start_date To $end_date\n";
    $csv_output=$heading;
    $line = "Comp_ID,CompanyName,Cust_Name,Plan_Type,Plan_Limit,Plan_Cost,Plan_Overage,Total_Usages,Total_Overage_Cost\n";
    $csv_output .= $line;
    $comma = ",";
        foreach ($total_call_log as $call_info) {
                $line1 = NULL;
                $line1 .= $call_info['Comp_ID'];
    $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['CompanyName'].'"';
                $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['Cust_Name'].'"';
    $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['Plan_Type'].'"';
                $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['Plan_Limit'].'"';
    $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['Plan_Cost'].'"';
                $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['Plan_Overage'].'"';
    $line1 .= $comma.'"'.$call_info['total_call_length'].'"';
                $line1 .= $comma.'"'.ceil($call_info['total_overage_cost']).'"';
    $csv_output .= $line1."\n";
           }
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv");
    print($csv_output);
}
```

What I want is, in the first row only all column should merge, and heading should be there in middle of the row.
Currently, heading($heading) is coming in first column only. How can I accomplish this????

Comment: Why aren't you using PHP's built in CSV functionality???

Comment: You can't merge cells in a .csv file.

Comment: +1 for @JohnConde. Also, in case you don't know what PHP's built-in CSV functionality looks like, take a look at the manual page for [`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Going along with what @SOliver has said, if you want merged cells, you should take a look at PEAR's Excel Writer http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected